# write double quote in file using php?

Tags: php

I want to write the following string in php using fwrite but i cant write that
string to be write is `$config['xxx']` :
it shows the error
can anybody help me?

here is my code

```
$stringData = "$config['xxx']";
 fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

I have the following error

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or `T_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING' in D:\xampplite\htdocs\PHP test\filecreate.php on line 6
```

Comment: Which error (I can imagine the one or other, but you should add those to your question)? And do you want to write the text as-is or the contents of the variable?

Comment: See the escaping rules in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double -- The actual issue with your example is that the parser was expecting PHP3-style array syntax `print "$config[xxx]";` which is valid within the double quotes. -- Also what is the actual purpose of your snippet?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    $stringData = '"'.$config['c'].'"';
     fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$stringData = "{$config['xxx']}"; //<<-- wrap with {...}
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

---

Or just:

```
$stringData = $config['xxx'];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

---

OR, if you actually want to write `$config['xxx']` to the file then you have to do escapes:

```
$stringData = "\$config['xxx']";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

Comment: How is `"{$config['xxx']}"` different from `$config['xxx']`?

Comment: @Tomalak -- it is not :-), see the 2nd part of my answer

Comment: Right. :) I *suspect* the OP is trying to write a literal `"$config['xxx']"` to the file. Might be wrong on that, though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the content of your string is being interpreted.  You need to escape the '$' with a slash like this:

```
$stringData = "\$config['c']";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

Comment: +1 that's my suspicion exactly. Alternative: use single quotes to prevent variable expansion: `$stringData = '$config[\'xxx\']';`

Answer (score 2):

Remember that php will try to parse `$___` formats in double quotes. E.g.

```
$foo = 'bar';
echo "$foo"; // outputs bar because it parses the variable
```

To avoid that, you can escape the `$` using `\$` within the string. e.g.

```
$stringData = "\$config['xxx']";
```

That is to say, if you want the *literal text* `$config['xxx']` to show up in the file. If you want the *value* of `$config['xxx']` in the file, you can use braces or just assign it that variable:

```
// just the variable
$stringData = $config['xxx'];

// with braces so the interpreter can parse it correctly
$stringData = "{$config['xxx']}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Write Double quotation inside single Single quotation

```
$stringData = '$config["xxx"]';
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the single qoutes...The double qoutes tell PHP to check if there are any variables in it. Therefore, you should always use the single quotes if you have a string. Even if there are variables in it...because, than you need to pull the variable out of the string, like it must be: $bla = 'I have some '.$variable.' here';.

So in your case, try: $stringData = '$config[\'xxx\']';

Answer (score 0):

If you need to output the value in $config['xxx'] wrapped with `"`'s, this syntax is usefull:

```
$stringData = "\"{$config['xxx']}\"";
```